# Run maven build from Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio for Maven Java API project

Tags: java, maven, redhat, jdeveloper

I am using Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio Version: 11.3.0.GA. I have imported a existing Java Maven API project into my workspace. I have also configured Maven 3.5.3 and setting.xml to my studio.

I am trying to run below mvn cmd from my studio on my imported java api maven project.

```
mvn clean package  -Dmaven.test.skip=true  -pl project-Sample-name -am -Dglobal.version=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

**Q1)** How to configure and run the above *cmd* from my Studio.

I right clicked on parent pom.xml `->Run As->Maven Build->Edit Configuration` and Launch screen opens. I dont know how to proceed further after this. Please advice.
[image: Edit Maven Configuration & Launch Screen:]

Answer (score 0):

- `clean` and `package` will be in *Goals* on the *Main* tab
- system properties such as `maven.test.skip=true` can be defined on *JRE* tab in *VM arguments*
- There is no need to specify `-pl project-Sample-name -am` when you have all required projects imported in Red Hat Developer Studio